# Water drainage from AC to a bucket kept on floor

Tags: newtonian-gravity, pressure, water, fluid-statics, flow

I have a split AC at home, the water outlet pipe from that was extended and kept into a bucket so that the water doesn't make puddles on the floor . The AC mechanic told when the bucket fills with water and the pipe gets submerged the water would stop flowing  and it would start leaking from the split AC unit from the top. I argued against it and told gravity would take care of it even if the pipe gets submerged since the water is coming from an upper level (atleast 8 feet difference) , the water would flow down from pipe to the bucket and the bucket should eventually overflow. Turns out the mechanic was right , as soon as the tip of the pipe got submerged , water started overflowing from top. I still don't know why it would happen. Can someone explain .  Crude image for the situation https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PjTF.jpg

Comment: I think the bore of the AC outlet is quite narrow. In a narrow pipe air-locking is common and water won't flow anymore. It is a bad design of the AC water vent rather. See Wiki on Air lock. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_lock

Comment: Just out of interest, what good is having a bucket if you intended to let it overflow?  How did you intend to dispose of the water?

Comment: @M.Farooq that does seems right , but wouldnt it happen without the bucket also ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft , there are some plants in the balcony ,i just use the water collected to water them . A little bit overflow if bucket fills up is ok , but i didnt want it to puddle up all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, when the bottom pipe is submerged in the bucket, the pressure of the water surrounding the mouth of this pipe will be  $$\tag 1 P=P_0+\rho gh$$ where $h$ is the depth of the pipe, $P_0$ is atmospheric pressure, $\rho$ is the density of water and $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity.

Even though at the top point where the water is released by the AC outlet, the water there is being pulled down by gravity, there will be a point when even the pressure in the pipe there will be exceeded by the pressure given by equation (1), as $h$ in equation (1) increases.

The point when this happens does depend on the height of the AC unit, but when $P\gt P_{AC}$ (the pressure at the top), the  water in the pipe will stop flowing downward, and the AC unit will leak at the top.

Comment: This doesn't make sense unless your $\rho$ is an indicator of friction inside the pipe.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Carl Witthoft $\rho$ is the density of the water. How did you get “friction”?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft since the water column in the pipe is at a much higher height , its pressure would be more than the bucket .

Comment: @Rahul Correct. And when the depth of the water gets to a certain point, then the pressure will be greater than at the top.

Comment: @josephh  i just added a rough image of the situation https://imgur.com/SQFTe8W . my point was since h2  is always greater than h1  , its gh2 will be greater than gh1.   apologies for the squiggly drawing

Comment: Please note that the $h$ in the $\rho gh$ above is depth of the pipe $h$ in the fluid, and _not_ the height of the pipe. Cheers.

Comment: @Rahul " _i just added a rough image of the situation_ " Please add this image to the question. It really needs it to understand what is happening. Even though it is a crude image, it would be very helpful

Comment: @josephh I don't understand your reasoning then, since in the absence of friction, water will seek its own level regardless of the depth of the exit end of the pipe.  If that weren't true then barometers wouldn't work.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Hi Carl.  "_water will seek its own level_" No one is disputing this. Again, why would you say that? Who said it did not?